# Skype Interview API throws JSON Parsing error, when provided position code in payload

Tags: node.js, json, skype, skypedeveloper

> Sadly this question is not relevant anymore, since Microsoft decided to retire the api [Read the details here](https://go.skype.com/skype.interviews.retire)

I am trying to implement skype interview api, when I provide payload to it, it throws JSON parsing error. If I provide an empty payload it works fine. When i provide any other payload mentioned [here](https://dev.skype.com/interviews), it works. But as soon as I provide position code as mentioned in the above link it fails.  Here is the code I am using -

```
exports.getLink = (req, res) => {
  let payload = {
    "code": "RENE2010"
  }
    , stringifyPayload = JSON.stringify(payload)

  let token = generateToken(stringifyPayload)
  fetch(config.skype.url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    },
    body: stringifyPayload
  })
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(jsonResult => {
      utils.sendResponse(res, jsonResult)
    }, err => {
      utils.sendResponse(res, null, 400, 'ERROR', err)
    }).catch(ex => {
      utils.sendResponse(res, null, 400, 'Exception', ex)
    })
}
```

And here is the `generateToken` Method -

```
let generateToken = (content) => {
  let token = jwt.sign({
    jti: Guid.raw(),
    iat: new Date().getTime(),
    iss: config.skype.api_key,
    sub: sha256(content),
    exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 10
  }, config.skype.app_secret)
  return token
}
```

And here is the error which I am getting -

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FetchError: invalid json response body at https://interviews.skype.com/api/interviews reason: Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0
    at /Users/xxx/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:272:32
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:9550) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:9550) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`

if I try to print the result without parsing into json this is the error I get -

```
{
  size: 0,
  timeout: 0,
  [Symbol(Body internals)]:
   { body:
      PassThrough {
        _readableState: [ReadableState],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [WritableState],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        _transformState: [Object] },
     disturbed: false,
     error: null },
  [Symbol(Response internals)]:
   { url: 'https://interviews.skype.com/api/interviews',
     status: 400,
     statusText: 'Bad Request',
     headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object] },
     counter: 0 } }
{ FetchError: invalid json response body at https://interviews.skype.com/api/interviews reason: Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0
    at /Users/xxx/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:272:32
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  message:
   'invalid json response body at https://interviews.skype.com/api/interviews reason: Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0',
  type: 'invalid-json' }
```

Comment: change `.then(result => result.json())` to 
`.then(result => {
     console.log(result);
     return result.json()
})`
So you can read that error message starting with an `I`...

Comment: Actually I did that and couldn't get any clue, I have updated the question with result.

Comment: Hi @Jeet can you post the payload you are posting to the API?

Comment: @yodebu Payload is already provided in the code above.